# access the response from a web coded performance test

Tags: c#, performance-testing

```
WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest((this.Context["Environment"].ToString() + "/IBWeb/DefaultSB.aspx"));
request1.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Referer", (this.Context["Environment"].ToString() + "/IBWeb/")));
ExtractHiddenFields extractionRule1 = new ExtractHiddenFields();
extractionRule1.Required = true;
extractionRule1.HtmlDecode = true;
extractionRule1.ContextParameterName = "1";
request1.ExtractValues += new EventHandler<ExtractionEventArgs>(extractionRule1.Extract);
yield return request1;
request1 = null;
```

I have a coded web performance test as mentioned above.. The test runs without any issues..But I would like to access the output/response from the `WebTestRequest` object. what is the best approach to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

add PostRequest event handler

```
request1.PostRequest += new EventHandler<PostRequestEventArgs>(request1_PostRequest);
```

handler method:

```
void request1_PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
{
    String responseBody = e.Response.BodyString;
}
```