# Extract Text from Response Body in Coded Webtest using vb

Tags: vb.net, performance, visual-studio, webtest

I have a Web performance Script in Visual Studio. I have turned this into Coded Webtest in VB by clicking on the Generate Code button.

In my web test there are a 5 functions. Apart from the 1st the others are for SQL Procedures.

Among a few things, I need a web request that does a certain action. Based on that action, In the response body - it generates a Unique Id.

I need this Id to make it accessible across all the functions.

The Response body is something like this :

```
0x00000000  7B  22  69  64  22  3A  36  35  33  30  36  36  33  7D            {"id":2133221}
```

Now I wanted to know, how do I do it.  I just need `2133221`.

I tried
using the Context Parameter name and appending it to a .to string...it did not work. I tried doing by looking over the net and trying out a few options. I'm lost now. Can anyone help.

Comment: I have edited your question. If I have misunderstood what you indended then please [edit] it to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is the below one.

```
str = "0x00000000 7B 22 69 64 22 3A 36 35 33 30 36 36 33 7D {""id"":2133221}"

arr = Split(str, ":")
strID = Left(arr(1), len(arr(1)) - 1)

msgbox strId
```

However, If you still need a more robust one, try regex

Comment: This is good in a normal case, but what im trying to do is in Coded Webtest . where i would need the request's response first . Thanks

Comment: Could you please update your original post with the code that you have tried... I would be able to understand the situation a bit more

Comment: I will do it in a few minutes. Sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [access the response from a web coded performance test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082377/access-the-response-from-a-web-coded-performance-test) for how to access the response ina coded test. While it is in C# the VB style is similar.

For your case the displayed string shows a hex dump of the actual body. Th ebody does not include the `0x00000000  7B  22  69  64  22  3A  36  35   33  30  36  36  33  7D` part.

A simple approach to getting the wanted Id string is to use a `Extract text` extraction rule with a `Start with` of `"id":` and an `Ends with` of `"`. This will need to be done on the ".webtest" file.

I strongly recommend against converting web tests to coded tests. It loses all the high level structure of the ".webtest" format. The Web Test Editor has many facilities for easily enhancing and changing tests, all of them are lost when changing to a coded test. A little learning about extraction and validation rules gives you many facilities. If you are happy working with the VB of a coded test then you should also be happy to write plugins so look at [web test request plugins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514192(v=vs.110).aspx) and [web test plugins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191(v=vs.110).aspx).