# Is it possible to convert a Visual Studio Load Test from coded to visual?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have created a VS Load Test (.webtest) from scratch by recording from browser. Then I generated a coded version in C# and made some changes to customize it. My question is: Is there any way to update the original visual .webtest from the updated coded version to be that code changes reflected?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You might be successful with an iterative approach. Take the original ".webtest" file and convert it to C# code. Compare that code against your modified C# code. Adjust the ".webtest" so is more like the modified code. Convert again and repeat. The "adjustments" could include adding or deleting requests until the request names match in the generated code. Then adding or removing other items. You might also move parts of your modified code into methods that you can then rewrite as plugins, validation rules or extraction rules.

See also the last paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308132/546871). Although it refers to VB it applies equally well to C#.